# Prevent logging personally-identify or sensitive data with generic type that excludes sensitive properties

Tags: c#, types, compile-time, redaction, compile-time-type-checking

I want to enhance my logger with a compile-time safety check that prevents me from logging personally-identifying or sensitive data. Here's what I imagine the interface could look like:

```
logger.LogInfo(safeuser => $"Logging out sensitive data @{safeuser.lastname}", user);
// Error: SafeToLog<User> does not contain a definition for 'lastname'
```

This line should not compile.

The regular `User` class has properties `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `createdAt`, `roleId`, `password` etc. Some of those fields are perfectly fine to log, like `id` and `roleId`. The ones that are unsafe to log will be marked with attributes like `[PersonallyIdentifying]` or `[Secret]`.

I want a type like `SafeToLog<T>` that has methods for every safe-to-log property of T, but no methods for the unsafe-to-log properties. So `SafeToLog<User>` should have properties `id`, `createdAt`, and `roleId`. It should NOT have properties `firstname`, `lastname` or `password`.

Is it possible to implement the `SafeToLog` type? In Typescript I could use the `Omit` helper type to construct this, but I don't know how to do it in C#.

---

Furthermore, would it be possible to prevent accidental misuse of the logger? In the sample above, a careless developer could still refer to `user` in the log string, ignoring `safeuser` and bypassing the safety check. Can I somehow enforce that only the variables provided in the lambda are referenced in the log message?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? If so please post an answer, I've seen this https://stackoverflow.com/q/33148957/495455 but am hoping there is something in-built.