# JsonConverter return empty value

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm creating a `JsonConverter` which will mask some sensitive information when logging it.

Here is my model:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `JsonConverter` that I created:

```
public class StudentJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private string[] _targetfields;

    public StudentJsonConverter(string[] targetFields)
    {
        _targetfields = targetFields;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        foreach (var prop in value.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (_targetfields.FirstOrDefault(x => x == prop.Name) != null)
            {
                prop.SetValue(value, MaskString(prop.GetValue(value, null).ToString()), null);
            }
        }

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private static string MaskString(string sensitiveInformation) => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sensitiveInformation) ? null : new string('*', sensitiveInformation.Length);
}
```

Here's how I am implementing the conversion:

```
string[] mask = { "Name" };

Student student = new Student { Name = "name", Phone = "1234" };

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new StudentJsonConverter(mask));
settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

var serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student, settings);
Console.WriteLine(serializedString);
```

When I run this, the output is `{}`.

what my expected output should be `{"Name" : "****", "Phone" : "1234"}`

Comment: Would you be open to alternative solutions to the actual problem, rather than to your attempt at a solution? In which case I'd suggest to not interfere with JSON serialization but with logging. (Including actually _using_ a Loggingframework instead of Console.WriteLine)

Comment: Hello @Fildor, Yes I'm open on other approach. I already I see other method like the Jsanitizer. My main object is that the field that I will mask should be dynamic that means I can add/remove the masking using the config.

Comment: you need to use deepcopy of serializer without your converter ... with `settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` you just masking the problem ...

Comment: btw ... `Student` class is mutable ... so after serialization data are f-up (because you chnage the value inside serializer) ...

Comment: hehe ... naive solution is replace `writer.WriteStartObject()` with `serializer.Converters.Remove(this)` and `writer.WriteEndObject()` with `serializer.Converters.Add(this)` ... but don't... don't do this :D

Comment: Why not just mark the property with [JsonIgnore] and it won't even be serialised in the first place?  If you are just masking it, then removing it is even better, right?

Comment: @Neil - the querent wants to *mask some sensitive information when **logging** it.*  They may not want to mask it when serializing over the wire or persisting to database, which `[JsonIgnore]` would do.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a converter, it will be easier to solve your problem with a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that replaces the actual value of selected properties with `"***"` during serialization.

The contract resolver from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33149572) by [Tom Bowers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2862621/tom-bowers) to *[Replace sensitive data value on JSON serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148957/replace-sensitive-data-value-on-json-serialization)* can be modified to meet your needs:

```
public class RedactingContracResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    // Adapted from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33149572
    // By https://stackoverflow.com/users/2862621/tom-bowers
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148957/replace-sensitive-data-value-on-json-serialization
    // To pass in a list of types + members to redact.
    readonly string? redactedValue;
    readonly List<(Type type, HashSet<string> memberNames)> membersToRedact;

    public RedactingContracResolver(string? redactedValue, params (Type type, string [] memberNames) [] membersToRedact)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(membersToRedact);
    
        this.redactedValue = redactedValue;
        this.membersToRedact = membersToRedact
            .Select(p => (p.type, p.memberNames.ToHashSet()))
            .ToList();
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        foreach (var toRedact in membersToRedact.Where(p => p.type.IsAssignableFrom(member.ReflectedType) == true && p.memberNames.Contains(member.Name)))
        {
            property.ValueProvider = new StringValueProvider(redactedValue);
            // As it is, the returned contract will throw an error if you attempt to use it to deserialize a redacted property.
            // If you would rather the redacted property be skipped during deserialization, uncomment the following line:
            // property.ShouldDeserialize = static _ => false;
        }
        return property;
    }   
}

public class StringValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    private readonly string? _value;

    public StringValueProvider(string? value) => this._value = value;
    public void SetValue(object target, object? value) => throw new NotSupportedException(nameof(SetValue));
    public object? GetValue(object target) => _value;
}
```

Then to redact members named `Name` **from all types**, use it as follows:

```
string[] mask = { "Name" };
RedactingContracResolver resolver = new("***", (typeof(object), mask));
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new()
{
    ContractResolver = resolver,
    // Add other settings as required
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
};
```

Or to redact `Name` only from `Student` (and any derived types) pass `typeof(Student)` rather than `typeof(object)`:

```
string[] mask = { nameof(Student.Name) };
RedactingContracResolver resolver = new("***", (typeof(Student), mask));
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new()
{
    ContractResolver = resolver,
    // Add other settings as required
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
};
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/foscPP).

Notes:

- Newtonsoft [recommends](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver) to cache and reuse contract resolvers to improve performance.
- For a discussion of when to use a contract resolver vs when to use a converter, see *[JSON.net ContractResolver vs. JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41088492)*.
- Members of any type can be redacted, not just string-valued members.
- I don't recommend masking a sensitive string with another string **of the same length** as this may still give hints about the sensitive information being redacted.  (E.g. knowing the length of a password may make it easier to guess.)  But if you **must** do this, modify the resolver as follows:

  ```
  public class RedactingContracResolver : DefaultContractResolver
  {
      // Adapted from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33149572
      // By https://stackoverflow.com/users/2862621/tom-bowers
      // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148957/replace-sensitive-data-value-on-json-serialization
      // To pass in a list of types + members to redact.
      readonly List<(Type type, HashSet<string> memberNames)> membersToRedact;

      public RedactingContracResolver(params (Type type, string [] memberNames) [] membersToRedact)
      {
          ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(membersToRedact);

          this.membersToRedact = membersToRedact
              .Select(p => (p.type, p.memberNames.ToHashSet()))
              .ToList();
      }

      protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
      {
          var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
          foreach (var toRedact in membersToRedact.Where(p => p.type.IsAssignableFrom(member.ReflectedType) == true && p.memberNames.Contains(member.Name)))
          {
              property.ValueProvider = new RedactedStringValueProvider(property.ValueProvider);
              // As it is, the returned contract will throw an error if you attempt to use it to deserialize a redacted property.
              // If you would rather the redacted property be skipped during deserialization, uncomment the following line:
              // property.ShouldDeserialize = static _ => false;
          }
          return property;
      }   
  }

  public class RedactedStringValueProvider : IValueProvider
  {
      IValueProvider? baseProvider;

      public RedactedStringValueProvider(IValueProvider? baseProvider) => this.baseProvider = baseProvider;
      public object? GetValue(object target)
      {
          var baseValue = baseProvider?.GetValue(target);
          if (baseValue is not string s || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
              return null;
          return new string('*', s.Length);
      }

      public void SetValue(object target, object? value) => throw new NotSupportedException(nameof(SetValue));
  }
  ```

  And call its constructor as follows:

  ```
  string[] mask = { "Name" };
  RedactingContracResolver resolver = new((typeof(object), mask));
  ```

  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/89IkAs).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to not serialize the sensitive object in the first place.

Maybe do something like this:

```
public static class StudentEx
{
    public static Student Mask(this Student sensitive) =>
       new Student{ Name = "***", Phone = sensitive.Phone };
}
```

and then use it like

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student.Mask(), settings));
```

---

You could make it somewhat configurable, too

```
public static class StudentEx
{
    public static Action<Student> MaskName = s => s.Name = "***";
    public static Action<Student> MaskPhone = s => s.Phone = "***";

    public static Student Mask(this Student sensitive, Action<Student> maskingAction)
    {
       var masked = maskingAction(new Student{ Name = sensitive.Name, Phone = sensitive.Phone });
       return maksed;
    }
}
```

and usage

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student.Mask(StudentEx.MaskName), settings));
```

This does not interfere with the default serialization of the type, which may still be needed unmasked, does not mutate the original instance and is less effort and - at least for me - is more readable than crafting a custom  JsonConverter.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I already found solution that fit in the requirement. So basically, I would not using the JsonConverter, instead I will use the JToken parser. This was also in Newtonsoft.Json package. I now directly masked the sensitive data in the JSON string. Using the solution I came up, I will only update minor code to implement the masking and all object that are creating logs will now updated. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm